# Habilitar os outros inputs apenas se um input estiver preenchido

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Tenho 6 inputs, CPF, email1, email2, celular1, celular2 e nome.

Preciso que o input CPF esteja preenchido para que os outros 5 inputs possam ser habilitados para o preenchimento, enquanto o CPF não estiver preenchido os outros campos devem estar desativados.

Estou utilizando HTML e JQuery no meu código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  validate();
  $('#cpf, #nome, #email,#email2, #celular #celular2').change(validate);
});

function validate() {
  if ($('#nome').val().length < 0 &&
    $('#email').val().length < 0 &&
    $('#email2').val().length < 0 &&
    $('#celular').val().length < 0 &&
    $('#celular2').val().length < 0) {
    $("#cpf").prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $("#cpf").prop("disabled", false);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row ">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12 msg_error text-center">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-6 " autocomplete="off">
    <label>CPF: <span>*</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="cpf teste" class="form-control cpfcnpj " placeholder="CPF" maxlength="14" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-6" autocomplete="off">
    <label>Nome: <span>*</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="nome" class="form-control nome" placeholder="Nome completo" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6" autocomplete="off">
    <label>E-mail <span>*</span></label>
    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control email" placeholder="E-mail" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6" autocomplete="off">
    <label>Confirme seu E-mail <span>*</span></label>
    <input type="email" id="email2" onpaste="return false" ondrop="return false" autocomplete="off" class="form-control email" placeholder="E-mail" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-6" autocomplete="off">
    <label>Celular: <span>*</span></label>
    <input id="celular" type="text" placeholder="(00) 00000-0000" class="form-control telefone required" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-6" autocomplete="off">
    <label>Confirme seu celular: <span>*</span></label>
    <input id="celular2" type="text" placeholder="(00) 00000-0000" class="form-control telefone required" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-left">
    <label>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                </label>
    <button id="button-next" class="btn btn-primary">Avançar</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Ericka, por favor, adicione em sua pergunta o código JavaScript que você está tentando fazer.

Comment: adicionei o script

Answer (score -2):

No JQuery existe o `.on` e o `.bind`, você pode utiliza-los para ficar checando se o input cpf teve alteração, ou seja, quando tiver alteração você pode executar um código que verifica se ele está preenchido ou não, permitindo tornar o disabled true ou false.

Para ficar monitorando as alterações no input cep e executar um código você pode usar `$("#cpf").on("input", function(){}`.

Fazendo dessa forma funciona muito bem:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nome, #email,#email2, #celular, #celular2').prop("disabled", true);
});

$("#cpf").on("input", function() {
   if ($('#cpf').val().length >= 11) {
    $('#nome, #email,#email2, #celular, #celular2').prop('disabled', false); 
   }else{
    $('#nome, #email,#email2, #celular, #celular2').prop("disabled", true);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row ">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12 msg_error text-center">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-6 " autocomplete="off">
    <label>CPF: <span>*</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="cpf" class="form-control cpfcnpj " placeholder="CPF" maxlength="14" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-6" autocomplete="off">
    <label>Nome: <span>*</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="nome" class="form-control nome" placeholder="Nome completo" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6" autocomplete="off">
    <label>E-mail <span>*</span></label>
    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control email" placeholder="E-mail" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6" autocomplete="off">
    <label>Confirme seu E-mail <span>*</span></label>
    <input type="email" id="email2" onpaste="return false" ondrop="return false" autocomplete="off" class="form-control email" placeholder="E-mail" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-6" autocomplete="off">
    <label>Celular: <span>*</span></label>
    <input id="celular" type="text" placeholder="(00) 00000-0000" class="form-control telefone required" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-6" autocomplete="off">
    <label>Confirme seu celular: <span>*</span></label>
    <input id="celular2" type="text" placeholder="(00) 00000-0000" class="form-control telefone required" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-left">
    <label>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                </label>
    <button id="button-next" class="btn btn-primary">Avançar</button>
  </div>

</div>
```